# Why didn't Royal Navy (columns of) ships turn outwards, rather than inwards?

Tags: naval

[Wikipedia has a colorful GIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Victoria_collision_sequence.gif) on [*Victoria* – *Camperdown* disaster](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/70377).

[image]

Then I read about [Admiral Sir Percy Scott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percy_Scott#Later_career).

> In July 1908 came what is referred to as the *second signalling incident*. Beresford signalled to the columns of the third division of the fleet, which were under Scott's command, to turn inwards together. As the two columns were at the time steaming on a parallel course with a separation of only 1,200 yards (six cables distance), this would have caused the leading ships, [HMS *Good Hope*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Good_Hope_(1901)) and [*HMS Argyll*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Argyll_(1904)) to collide. Scott ordered the captain of the *Good Hope* to disobey the order, thus avoiding a repetition of the [*Victoria – Camperdown*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinking_of_HMS_Victoria) disaster.

##### Isn't turning outwards safer? Why didn't these ships turn outwards instead? See beneath picture.

[image]

Comment: Dr Alexandrler Clarke has a [talk on the subject of the collision](https://youtu.be/-_wC8Fnp_9A) which may contain what you're looking for. It's 90m so I haven't listened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **combat**, ships of the era needed to maneuver precisely to bring their power to bear at just the right moment.

In **training**, they need to maneuver precisely, in close proximity to each other, so they have confidence that they can do it in combat.

Admiral Tryon is dead, we cannot know what he intended to happen. But it seems obvious that he *thought* the maneuvering was safe enough for peacetime training purposes.

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't answer about the "second signalling incident"?

Comment: @user35024, you should not accept my answer this early, especially if you have questions about it. I'd suggest you un-accept for now. The second incident shows that even after the Victoria incident, the RN found it necessary to maneuver ships in dangerous proximity. If you read about Jutland, some things were wrong with the command culture of the RN, but I don't think close maneuvers were one of them.